# How do I align texts and an image inside a div?

Tags: css, html, alignment

Basically I have two pieces of text and an image.

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="title">Text</span>
    <img src="an_image.png" />
    <span class="note">Other Text</span>
</div>
```

I want all the elements to be at the bottom of the container div, the title to aligned to the left, and the note all the way to the right. The image will be right next to the title and aligned to the bottom of the title text. So far the only way I have gotten this to work is by using relative/absolute position. Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish. I can change the width and height of the container and the title, image, and notes will align properly to the bottom, left, and right just like so:

[image]

Comment: Technically, positioning (relative and absolute) _are_ doing it with css

Comment: Why aren't you happy with your `relative`/`absolute` solution? Is there some downside to it?

Comment: @thirtydot Yeah, his problem is that he isn't happy with it ;) @kailoon Throw up an image of what you want it to look like.  I'm having trouble visualizing this.

Comment: @Levi: Okay, I'll get an image up when I can. =) I'm not happy since I feel like it will break whenever we style the font for the title or notes differently. I'll have to manually reposition it. It would be nice if it did it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .container { vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; border: solid 1px Gray; }
    .note { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
  </style>

  <div class="container">
      <span class="title">Text</span>
      <img src="an_image.png" height="100" width="100" />
      <span class="note">Other Text</span>
  </div>
```

Sorry, Updated solution... Here's the working [link](http://jsbin.com/uwilo3)

Comment: I think this was the first thing I tried. The "note" span does not end up aligned to the bottom (sadly). I would think it should, but HTML/CSS has a habit of surprising me.

Comment: Actually, this works. My mistake was I added float:left to title. So basically the title and the image will align themselves properly, and we leave absolute positioning just to the note itself. This to me, is a workable solution. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play around with the vertical-align, but it's kinda evil..i usually use the absolute position. You can test by yourself on the [W3C Tryit Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align)

Comment: I don't know about vertical align, but w3schools is certainly evil.  See the proof: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Nvm... I thought you were commenting on the other web site.